# is_dir function can't read directories help php

Tags: php

I just got ran into a problem with is_dir() function ...

the code is here:

```
<?php
$dir=$_GET['x'];
echo $dir;    
if(is_dir($dir)) {
    echo "dir";
    echo "<br>";
    echo is_dir($dir);
} else {
    echo "not";
    echo "<br>";
    echo is_dir($dir);
}

?>
```

the problem is that the is_dir() function is not recognizing the directories with plus (+) sign, so if a directory is for example named like this:

```
this+folder+cant+be+checked
```

and the link is like this :

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\New\A\this+folder+cant+be+checked
```

and if I enter this link in the address bar ahead of the variable x here, it goes automatically into else clause and echos "not" (also point to be noted is that I am inserting these links manually not creating it myself, but copying it from the file explorer, means going to the specific location, copy the link and pasting it ahead of the x variable ...

it works fine if a directory name is normal and having space for example the folder is "this folder cant be checkednot" and the link is this:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\New\A\this folder cant be checkednot
```

here it will go in if clause, also I can't understand how to do that with url encoding because, when I enter the + sign link which gets store in $dir=$_GET['x'] , and when I echo the $dir variable, its doesn't show the + sign instead it shows empty space.

However if I remove + sign from address bar, and put "%2B" it will work ..

```
http://localhost/New/A/try.php?x=C:\xampp\htdocs\New\A\this%2Bfolder%2Bcant%2Bbe%2Bchecked
```

but can't understand, how to detect if there's a + sign named directory and upon detecting it , how to change it to %2B ?

I tried this :

```
$dir=str_replace("%2B","+",$dir);
```

but doesn't work.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250236/discussion-on-question-by-umair-ali-is-dir-function-cant-read-directories-help).

Comment: Simplest solution is: if you are in control of the request, then URL encode it: ?x=D%3A%5Cdirectory%5CsubDirectory%5Cthis%2Bis%2Btest%2Bdir . Or, if you have a form that is sending the data, then the above will get encoded when it conains the plus signs anyway.  Are you in control of the request URL?

Comment: @Rajan  imagine a file manager which is showing the name "\this+folder+cant+be+checked" of the folder which you created yourself and windows file manager shows the same because you named it like that way, now when you click on that directory it sends the exact name to the $_GET global variable, so it will become just the exact GET request that I made above , Now how is the above going to help when the + sign is undetectable , I would use rawurlencode or urlencode , but that's only possible if the + sign in the url is detectable. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I got the solution I was a bit confused because the actual code of my file manager was really huge, so I couldn't post the whole code here, Instead I was trying to make a solution for it, with an example code that I have given above in the question, Actually My question was already Answered, by many people, Hope I am allowed to mention their name, ad7six,cbroe,syscall Thanks for the help, so just to answer this question and to remove confusion I have made a short code of the file manager separately:

```
<?php

$current_dir=$_GET['x']; //taking the directory from browser GET variable..

if($handle=opendir($current_dir)){

    while(false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
        if ($file == '.' || $file == '..') {
            continue;
        } else if (is_dir($current_dir . '/' . $file)) { //directory me jo directory ha usk  sath  append krdo $file jo k ek or directory ha
            $myshell = basename(__FILE__);

            $encoded_file_url = str_replace("+", rawurlencode("+"), $file);
            echo "<br>";
            echo "<a href='$myshell?x=$current_dir/$encoded_file_url'>[$file]</a>";
            echo "<br>";
        }else{
            echo $file."  "."[this is a file]"."<br>"."<br>";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

sometimes you see things which are so obvious this is the same case, so I realized that if I am putting the url manually by my own hands and the browser is just removing the + sign and replacing it with space, there's def no way I can do anything about it like encoding the + sign etc, then I checked my file manager was showing the name of the file, and I hit my head with a wall , and I end up resolving the issue I was having by placing the str_repace() function with rawurlencode() function , also made a code separately just for solution , thanks for the help guys..